# Git/BitBucket Pull/Commit Merge Error

Tags: git, commit, bitbucket, pull

Sometimes when me and my team mates are working on this project, and I try to pull with commits ready to merge with the pull I get this weird "Conflict" and I don't get any specific error, but this shows up at random spots in the code. (with the hash changing each time I encounter this).

[image: Git/BitBucket Pull/Commit Merge Error]

What does the `<<<<<< HEAD`, `=======`, and `>>>>>>>> HASH` mean when it shows up? That way I can fix it instead of just deleting them and just re-pushing.... which is what I have been doing, but is probably bad.

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on the basics of git.

Here is the chapter on merge conflicts from Git Pro which is a great and free book available directly from the git-scm site.

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging#Basic-Merge-Conflicts